# Advanced Installer MSI - The Package Can Only Be Run From A Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, advanced-installer

I am using advanced installer 11.4.1 to make an msi.

I want to run the .msi with `msiexec /qn` and not the `.exe`.

Advanced Installer makes 2 files as output (a .exe and a .msi)

When I run the .exe everything works fine.

```
Client.exe /qn /log "C:\mylog.log"
```

When I run the .msi I get no run and an error in the log

```
 msiexec /qn /i Client.msi /log "C:\mylog.log"
```

At the end of the .log file it reads..

```
Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

[image]

Here is the full log..

```
=== Logging started: 7/7/2020  9:54:58 ===
Action start 9:54:58: INSTALL.
Action start 9:54:58: AI_ResolveKnownFolders.
Action ended 9:54:58: AI_ResolveKnownFolders. Return value 1.
Action start 9:54:58: AppSearch.
Action ended 9:54:58: AppSearch. Return value 0.
Action start 9:54:58: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 9:54:58: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 9:54:58: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (B8:7C) [09:54:58:208]: Product: Pfile -- This package can only be run from a bootstrapper.

This package can only be run from a bootstrapper.
Action ended 9:54:58: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 9:54:58: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): AppsShutdownOption = All
Property(S): DiskPrompt = [1]
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {6C146AF2-91E8-4E74-B03B-53D4E7CC5F19}
Property(S): ButtonText_Install = &Install
Property(S): ButtonText_Remove = &Remove
Property(S): ButtonText_Repair = &Repair
Property(S): CLIENT_LICENSE_STRING = conn\whocares\456
Property(S): CLIENT_SERVICE_INI_PATH = NicksINI
Property(S): CLIENT_SETTINGS_PATH = c:\myDir
Property(S): CLIENT_SERVICE_CREDS_PATH = xyz456
Property(S): BannerBitmap = banner
Property(S): AI_LOG_CHECKBOX = 1
Property(S): PUP_CLIENT_PATH = C:\Users\admin2\Desktop\Client.zip
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): AI_BITMAP_DISPLAY_MODE = 0
Property(S): AI_Init_NewSeqDialog = [AI_ButtonText_Next_Orig]:[ButtonText_Next]:AI_INSTALL|[ButtonText_Next]:[[AI_CommitButton]]:AI_INSTALL|[AI_Text_Next_Orig]:[Text_Next]:AI_INSTALL|[Text_Next]:[Text_Install]:AI_INSTALL
Property(S): ButtonText_Next = &Next >
Property(S): RemoveIcon = removico
Property(S): InstallModeCustom = Custom
Property(S): InstallerIcon = insticon
Property(S): TabBackground = tabback
Property(S): AI_CF_TITLE_TEXT_STYLE = {\CfTitleFont}
Property(S): EnableUserControl = 1
Property(S): ProductVersion = 1.0.0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 3
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = OLDPRODUCTS;AI_NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): CtrlEvtRemoving = Removing
Property(S): Text_Install = Install
Property(S): ButtonText_Reset = &Reset
Property(S): WindowsTypeNT40 = Windows NT 4.0
Property(S): ARPCOMMENTS = This installer database contains the logic and data required to install Pfile.
Property(S): WindowsTypeNT40Display = Windows NT 4.0
Property(S): ButtonText_Finish = &Finish
Property(S): AiPrerequisitesColums = PrereqLabel,PrereqReq,PrereqFound,PrereqAction
Property(S): ButtonText_Browse = Br&owse...
Property(S): NewDirIcon = New
Property(S): ButtonText_Exit = &Exit
Property(S): CtrlEvtrepairs = repairs
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = DlgFont8
Property(S): ButtonText_OK = OK
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): ProductName = Pfile
Property(S): ButtonText_No = &No
Property(S): DialogBitmap = dialog
Property(S): AI_ThemeStyle = default
Property(S): Manufacturer = Nick
Property(S): UpDirIcon = Up
Property(S): CtrlEvtRepairing = Repairing
Property(S): CtrlEvtremoves = removes
Property(S): PROMPTROLLBACKCOST = P
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ButtonText_Ignore = &Ignore
Property(S): ProductCode = {744283F5-7EC5-4234-AFAF-5A4C36ECA4E9}
Property(S): ButtonText_Decline = &Decline
Property(S): WindowsType9XDisplay = Windows 9x/ME
Property(S): AI_CommitButton = ButtonText_Install
Property(S): ButtonText_Cancel = Cancel
Property(S): ExclamationIcon = exclamic
Property(S): WindowsType9X = Windows 9x/ME
Property(S): CtrlEvtChanging = Changing
Property(S): Text_Next = Next
Property(S): ButtonText_Resume = &Resume
Property(S): ButtonText_Yes = &Yes
Property(S): Wizard = Setup Wizard
Property(S): ButtonText_Retry = &Retry
Property(S): ButtonText_Return = &Return
Property(S): ButtonText_Accept = &Accept
Property(S): DlgTitleFont = {\DlgFontBold8}
Property(S): CtrlEvtchanges = changes
Property(S): InstallMode = Typical
Property(S): InstallModeComplete = Complete
Property(S): InstallModeTypical = Typical
Property(S): ButtonText_Back = < &Back
Property(S): Setup = Setup
Property(S): AI_EXE_EXTRACTION_FOLDER = [TempFolder]
Property(S): Progress1 = Installing
Property(S): Progress2 = installs
Property(S): AI_FrameColor = steelblue
Property(S): CompleteSetupIcon = completi
Property(S): AiStyleConditions =  
Property(S): CustomSetupIcon = custicon
Property(S): InfoIcon = info
Property(S): RepairIcon = repairic
Property(S): AI_PACKAGE_TYPE = x64
Property(S): AI_BUILD_NAME = DefaultBuild
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\nicksMSIlog.log
Property(S): PackageCode = {5C323F79-0B19-4D21-8F17-1388EF390F50}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\admin2\Desktop
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 3
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 28384
Property(S): MsiRestartManagerSessionKey = bccb9b797ff6da41b5a1c929efbf25a3
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\admin2\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\admin2\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\admin2\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 4095
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 2533
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = Admin2
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1032408829-1743725535-1994454344-1106
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = NICK-1903
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 19
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 9:54:58
Property(S): Date = 7/7/2020
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.3752.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.18362.719
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): USERNAME = User01
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\5234f9c.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\admin2\Desktop\ClientNet.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): SavedGamesFolder = C:\Users\admin2\Saved Games\
Property(S): WindowsLibrariesFolder = C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\
Property(S): PublicDocumentsFolder = C:\Users\Public\Documents\
MSI (s) (B8:7C) [09:54:58:271]: Product: Pfile -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (B8:7C) [09:54:58:271]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Pfile. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Nick. Installation success or error status: 1603.

=== Logging stopped: 7/7/2020  9:54:58 ===
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a launch condition imposed by Advanced Installer tool when you build an EXE with resources next to it. Check [this faq](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-errors.html#question145) in their user guide. As a workaround solution you can add in Builds view of your setup project a new build of type MSI. This way you will also build a setup package of MSI type only.

Comment: What is the equivalent to the "builds view" in advanced installer 11.4.1?

Comment: Can you assist in instructions how to change this installer "exe" (which calls another exe in its custom actions) from an exe to msi?

Comment: I do not have that old version of Advanced Installer, but if I remember right there should be a Media view or something - there is a section in your project where you could configure the type (EXE or MSI) of the setup being built by your project.

Comment: There is an [exe to msi](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-convert-exe-to-msi.html) article on Advanced Installer website. This should do what you are looking for.